# Triary-Heap-Ordered Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have a lab where I need to edit the given code for a binary heap-ordered tree into a triary heap ordered tree. (This is all in Java)

My thought for this is...

With a binary tree, you simple compare the left and right child.

For a triary tree, it seems that you should compare left child to middle child, then middle child to right child... does this sound correct?

Now to the important question.. I can NOT remember what the algorithm for a triary heap ordered tree was... I believe for a binary tree, its

```
parent = "child - 1 / 2"
```

so wouldnt triary just be...?

```
parent = "child - 1 / 3"
```

Comment: You need to review the heap property.  A 3-heap has exactly the same property, and it has nothing to do with comparisons between children.  As to the index convention, just try it.  Try filling in an array with the root at element 0 (or 1 if that's where your arrays start), its children at 1,2,3, then 1's children at 4,5,6 and 2's children at 7,8,9, etc.  What formula works?  If you want to master computer programming, you must be willing to think and puzzle things out before posting to SO.

Comment: Sorry, this wasn't helpful at all.

Comment: Let's do what I said:  If array position 0 is the root, and 1,2,3 are its children, then what function P(x) will return the index of the parent given the index of the child?  Try P(x) = (x - 1) / 3. (Your expressions are missing parentheses. They always equal to `child`.)  Does P(1)=0?  How about P(2) and P(3)?  If they are working, then try P(4).  The parent of 4 should be 1.  Does it work?  Keep going... If someone gives you these answers, you will not make progress.

Comment: Unfortunately... I feel like i'm already setup for failure by my colleges teaching methods. We were given an ENTIRE class with a binary tree completed.. and all we have to do is change it to a triary tree. I will attempt what you are saying,

Comment: So.. When getting a decimal value.. IE (9-1) / 3 = 2.66... Does this round up or down? The parent of 9 should be 2.

Comment: Read about integer arithmetic.  Integer division truncates the fraction.  (9-1)/3 = 8/3 = 2.

Comment: is the proper way to think about this.. comparing the 3 children? With the binary tree, you compare left child and right child. To me, it makes sense that I would need to compare left to middle, left to right ect.

Answer (score 0):

In binary tree it's not very clear when it's either left or right however in ternary search tree you can use greater than, less then and equal.

Comment: He said heap-ordered tree, not search tree.